# Submitting one form amongst multiple forms ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms, this, unique

I've been a lurker for some time, but this is my first post (and motivated me to sign up), I've searched countless posts, but can't find a solution that best works. This is part of a project where users search a database and have the option to add returned results to a saved location (posting the id, resid, to a separate mysql table).

The search function is in a separate php file, the relevant parts of the code are below (I've stripped out a lot of the formatting):

```
// Output HTML formats
    $html ='<tr >
      <form id="myForm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="resid" name="resid" value="ther3sidd">
        <input type="hidden" id="lesid" name="lesid" value="liD1">
        <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData()" value="Submit" />
      </form>
         </tr>';
```

The values "ther3sidd" and "liD1" get replaced with values unique to the item returned by the search, and are numerical values. There will also be multiple of the forms returned on the user facing page all with the same id of myForm (but different lesid and resid).

The search results are outputted to the page the user is on and a button can be pressed to add the result to a mysql table using the script below (stored in the page the user is on).

```
function SubmitFormData() {       
    var lesid = $('input[name="lesid"]').val();
    var resid = $('input[name="resid"]').val(); 
    var dataString = {lesid: lesid, resid: resid}

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'lesresadd.php',
        data: dataString, 
    })}
```

Below is the php file lesresadd.php (without the connection info)

```
$lessonid = $_POST['lesid'];
$resourceid = $_POST['resid'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO lessons_resources (lesson_id, resource_id)
VALUES ('$lessonid', '$resourceid')";

$result = $conn->query($sql)
```

The code works fine and can submit data to the mysql table, however, the main issue is that the values for resid and lesid are for the first result from the search function (and not the one selected with the button click). I know that I need to use 'this' somewhere on the variable, however, I am not sure of the correct syntax. For example, I have tried the following (and many variants on it):

```
var lesid = $this().('input[name="lesid"]').val();
```

But this does not work. Maybe, there is more I need to do to the code, and it isn't as simple as just adding 'this' somewhere. I am reasonably new to AJAX and entirely self taught from visiting sites just like stack overflow. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$this()` does not look valid, and I don't think that your problem is in any way related to PHP or AJAX - can you clarify what does not work yet? The title talks about something with multiple forms, but I cannot see from your question itself what that means

Comment: It should be `var lesid = $(this).val();` , do you have many of the first HTML forms on one page? you are using ID's and on multiple elements, this is pointless. You should change these to classes, and then bind an event to your submit button like: `$('.submitFromData').on('click',submitFormData());`

Comment: @LiamG There could be any number of forms returned depending on how specific the search term is (more specific, fewer forms, but potentially 10s or 100s still). If I use `var lesid = $(this).val();` how would this specifically pull out only the lesid rather resid (trying to understand the nature of it)?

Comment: @NicoHaase there could be a number of forms generated dynamically, all with the same format, shown in the first part of the code. I can get the data to post to a mysql table, however, it is only for the first returned form, not the one actually submitted.

Comment: Having a rethink of it now and it wouldn't really work.. are you printing the html forms using a loop in PHP? If so I could knock together a solution

Comment: @LiamG it's an array generated from the search query, then using foreach, to replace the values in the first bit of code. It might seem like I need to rethink how I go about doing this if it's not as simple as using `$this()` somewhere on the var in the script.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the neatest solution, but here goes:

```
$html = "";
$i = 1;
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($res))
{
    $html .='<tr>
        <input type="hidden" id="resid'.$i.'" name="resid" value="ther3sidd">
        <input type="hidden" id="lesid'.$i.'" name="lesid" value="liD1">
        <input type="button" class="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData('.$i.')" value="Submit" />
         </tr>';
    $i++;
}
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
function SubmitFormData(id) {       
    var lesid = $('#lesid'+id).val();
    var resid = $('#resid'+id).val(); 
    var dataString = {lesid: lesid, resid: resid}

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'lesresadd.php',
        data: dataString, 
    })}
```